# How to create Unique User ID in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, customization, user-defined-functions

I need to add a users from WordPress backend. So, I want to generate unique User IDs for them. But I can achieve it. Can somebody help me out on this.

Here is what I cam so far. It is better if I could append the WordPress default generated unique user id to end of my field.

```
// Customize the user fields
function custom_user_profile_fields($user) {

    $rand = randomGen(1000,5000,1);
    $auth_Token = '2021-ABCD-'.$rand[0];

  ?>
    <h3>Profile Information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="srn">Student Registration Number</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="srn" value="<?php echo (get_option('srn') ? esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'srn', $user->ID ) ) : $auth_Token); ?>" id="srn" readonly /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "custom_user_profile_fields" );

function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id) {
    # again do this only if you can
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
        return false;

    # save my custom field
    update_usermeta($user_id, 'srn', $_POST['srn']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
```

When a user added I can't get the previously saved Index Number to the field. It's generating another and showing again. As I am not an expert for this, could anybody help me out with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path to solve the problem, but you made some mistakes.

You can use the working code below:

### Creation of fields

```php
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'bks_add_student_reg_number_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'bks_add_student_reg_number_field' );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'bks_add_student_reg_number_field' );


function bks_add_student_reg_number_field( $user ) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="student_reg_number"><?php _e("Student Registration Number"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <?php if (is_object($user)) { ?>
                    <input type="text" name="student_reg_number" id="student_reg_number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'student_reg_number', $user->ID )); ?>" class="regular-text" readonly disabled="disabled"/><br />
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <input type="text" name="student_reg_number" id="student_reg_number" class="regular-text" /><br />
                    <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter Student registration number."); ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
```

This creates a field option at new user generation and edit form.

[image: new user field]

- The field is only enabled when a new user is created. If the registered user has already have a value the value would be shown with no access to change it.

### Save field value

```php
add_action( 'user_register', 'bks_student_reg_number_field' );

function bks_student_reg_number_field($user_id) {
    // You can maybe add checks here whch would determine if the users role is customer
    // or not or maybe validate the number.

    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
        return false;

    $reg_value = get_user_meta($user_id, 'student_reg_number', true);
    if (isset( $_POST['student_reg_number']) &&  $_POST['student_reg_number'] !== $reg_value) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'student_reg_number', $_POST['student_reg_number'].'-'.$user_id);
    }
}
```

Only `user_register` hook is used to prevent updation on profile edit.

[image: Field saved]

You can see the user_id appended with a `-` infront of it in the field and the field is readonly and disabled.

> If you want user to be able to edit the id after registering as well then. do the following.
>
> - Add `profile_update` hook. `add_action( 'profile_update', 'bks_student_reg_number_field' );` as well so that the code runs when you update the user as well.
> - Remove `readonly` and `disabled` attribute from the form.

The code is TESTED and **WORKS**.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I replaced this with my existing code. But it giving me an error. `Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in....`

Comment: @WPLearner, I have tested the code with the fresh install of wordpress and it still works. Can you paste the complete error ? so that I can check.

Comment: @WPLearner, I have fixed the code. Please check once.

Comment: I really appreciate your support. But unfortunately this code is not working. Steps followed, added both snippets to `functions.php` file. Then tried using `Users->Add New`. It's giving me a blank text field. Admin panel: https://ibb.co/Fh8vJdm. `functions.php` file https://ibb.co/ZLzNHqC

Comment: What do you want in that text field ? You have to fill something in that by yourself. @WPLearner